# Configuring Nuxt 3 to run behind reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to create a reverse proxy setup with Nginx for my frontend and backend.
My backend works fine behind the reverse proxy and its Swagger UI is accessible from the public URL through my web browser.
My frontend is not. My frontend is created using Typescript and Nuxt 3 (Vue).
What I want to accomplish as a reverse proxy mapping is something like the following:

Back-end: foo.com/leaf/api/x --> 127.0.0.1:8000/x
Front-end: foo.com/leaf/y --> 127.0.0.1:3000/y

To accomplish this I have added the following blocks to my nginx.conf in exactly the order shown here:

```
location /leaf/api/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
location /leaf/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
location / {
  root   html;
  index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

This configuration works for the backend but not for the Nuxt based frontend. When I run the Nuxt development server Nitro to test the setup and go to localhost/leaf in my browser it does seem to fetch Nuxt's entrypoint script perfectly fine but all later requests fail with a 404 or a 500:
[image: Requests after fetching the entrypoint script fail]

I see no error messages in the Nitro terminal process and I don't see anything helpful in the access log. I'm on Windows.

My nuxt.config.ts contains the following:

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  sourcemap: {
    server: true,
    client: true
  },
  ssr: false,

  css: [
    'primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css',
    'primevue/resources/primevue.css',
    'primeicons/primeicons.css',
    'primeflex/primeflex.css',
    '/assets/styles/layout.scss'
  ],
  build: {
    transpile: ['primevue', 'primeflex']
  },
  modules: [
    '@pinia/nuxt',
    '@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt',
  ],
  vite: {
    build: {
      sourcemap: 'inline'
    },
  },
})
```

Building the project and running it with node gives the same problem.

What am I doing wrong? What should I be doing to deploy my app in a reverse proxy environment if it's written in Nuxt?

Thanks in advance for your input,
Joshua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it by changing my location blocks to:

```
location /leaf/api/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
location /leaf/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

  # Needed for Node based applications ...
  # They only handle packets if the Host header is set to
  # the host in the URL **INCLUDING** the port ($proxy_port)
  proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Including the port from the proxy_pass (the one on which the application server runs) in the Host header of requests going to the Nuxt app seems to solve the issue. I don't know the details of this.